# How to get text inside script tag in HTML

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to scrape this site:

```
https://www.lanebryant.com/perfect-sleeve-swing-tunic-top/prd-356831#color/0000009320
```

I want to get type of clothing, i.e. the category of the clothing. 
There is a script on the page:
 [image]

How can I collect this text and get the category of the clothing which I have highlighted in the image? I have tried the following code but it returns nothing.

```
type = d.find_element_by_xpath("//script[@type='text/javascript']").text
print("hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii"+type)
```

d here is the driver

Comment: What is the problem exactly ? Triggering the fetch of the popups or finding the current category of the item ?

Comment: Excuse the obscurity. It is finding the current category of item

Answer (score 1):

Here you go...

1.Get the `innerHTML` of the scripts tag

2.Convert into `Json()` format

3.use the `parameter` and then get the value `tops`

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import json

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.lanebryant.com/perfect-sleeve-swing-tunic-top/prd-356831')
item = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
    (By.XPATH, "//script[@type='text/javascript'][contains(.,'window.lanebryantDLLite')]"))).get_attribute('innerHTML')
itemtext = item.split("=")[1].split(";")[0]  # This will return as string

itemjson = json.loads(itemtext.strip())  # Converted here into json format

itemtop = itemjson['page']['pageName']  # Use the parameter to get the text

print(itemtop.split(':')[1].strip())  # Split here to get only value tops
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this,

```
type = d.find_element_by_xpath('//script[@type="text/javascript"]').text
```

Also make a count of script tags in the page source.

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems with your current way is that you collect all scripts on the current page, you need to narrow it a bit.

This finds the correct script and then collects the category with the help of regex:

```
from lxml import html
import requests
import re
# create the regex
category_regex = re.compile(r'(?<="category": ").*(?=", "CategoryID")')
page = requests.get('https://www.lanebryant.com/perfect-sleeve-swing-tunic-top/prd-356831#color/0000009320')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
information = tree.xpath("//script[contains(text(), '\"page\": {    \"pageName\": \"Clothing :')]/text()")
print(category_regex.findall(str(information)))

Output: ['Tops']
```